# How to check in a string after the whitespace any character is there or not in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to check a string if any character is present after the whitespace. If not present i need to trim and remove the last whitespace.

I tied using trim() method but in the case of that it will trim the remaining part is any character is present after the whitespace.

Comment: Can you include sample data and your expected  result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String text="name is n";
  print(text.split(" ").last.isEmpty);
```

if the last value is false then there are character in last part and do any operation you want i hope it help.